# How to connect to azure VM with Remote desktop ActiveX?

Tags: azure, activex, remote-desktop

The Remote Desktop ActiveX does not react to the connect command when using connection parameters to connect to azure VM. The ActiveX window stays white instead of showing the remote desktop session initialization. How to correctly use the Remote desktop client ActiveX to connect to Azure?

.RDP file sample

```
full address:s:<cloudservice>.cloudapp.net
username:s:<username>
LoadBalanceInfo:s:Cookie: mstshash=<role>#<roleinstance>
```

I use ActiveX embedded in a WPF WindowsFormsHost. (I already tested with another LAN Pc and remote session is established successfully. (Server, username, and password provided).

```
<WindowsFormsHostEx x:Name="m_host" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
  <axMstscLib:AxMsTscAxNotSafeForScripting x:Name="m_remoteDesktop"/>
</WindowsFormsHostEx>
```

When trying to embed theses informations into the ActiveX. the command does not react. 
connected value stays to "2"... and no OnConnected, OnDisconnected, OnFatalError, OnLogonError occured.

```
        m_remoteDesktop.Server = "<cloudservice>.cloudapp.net";
        m_remoteDesktop.UserName = "<username>";
        IMsRdpClientAdvancedSettings settings = m_remoteDesktop.AdvancedSettings as IMsRdpClientAdvancedSettings;
        if (settings != null)
        {
            settings.LoadBalanceInfo = "Cookie: mstshash=<Role>#<RoleInstance>";
            settings.ClearTextPassword = "<rdp pass>";
        }
        m_remoteDesktop.Connect();
        short connected = m_remoteDesktop.Connected;
```

Answer (score 3):

settings.LoadBalanceInfo need a "\r\n" at the end to be effective.

```
settings.LoadBalanceInfo = "Cookie: mstshash=<Role>#<RoleInstance>"
```

to

```
settings.LoadBalanceInfo = "Cookie: mstshash=<Role>#<RoleInstance>\r\n"
```

Just adding that made my problem solved.